# How to print all number combinations from specific set of numbers?

Tags: python, list, numbers, range, combinations

I'm trying to get every number combination from a list of numbers.

Currently I can easily get this as a range, and I get every number combination I want within a set of 5 numbers (printed in 5 separate columns). What I can't figure out how to do is how to get every number combination from a very specific list of numbers that prints this exact same format from the existing code.

Below is what I have as the code to find the numbers within a range, and it works well:

```
for range_numbers in combinations(list(range(1,20)), 5): #This gives me every 5 number combination without repeating numbers.
    for nums in combinations(list(range(1,10)), 1): #this adds every combination of this range without repeating numbers, in a single column.
        combined = range_numbers + nums
        file_writer.writerow(combined)
        count += 1
```

What I want is to produce exactly the same results but from a list of specific numbers such as [2,3,5,7,9,12,13,15,19] for the 5 number combinations, and [3,7,8,10] for the 1 number combination added on.

Any help is appreciated, I've spent the last 8hrs googling and trying to figure this one out, which feels like it should be easy but my brain is just mush now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a direct substitution of operands:

```
from itertools import combinations, product
large = [2,3,5,7,9,12,13,15,19]
small = [3,7,8,10]

for range_numbers in combinations(large, 5):
    for nums in combinations(small, 1):
        ...
```

Perhaps better, use `product` to do this in a single loop, as Guido intended:

```
for combined in product( [list(combinations(large, 5)),
                          list(combinations(small, 1))] ):
```

Comment: This is perfect!!! Thank you so much! It's so amazing to spend all day on something and have it complete the task in 0.4388279914855957  seconds, hahaha Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.  Be *careful* with the list sizes.  If you have very long lists, look up the `chain` method to link the `combinations` and `product` generators.

Comment: Ok awesome! Thank you so much for the advice! I'll take a look into the chain method.